# Vagrant package does not package /home/vagrant/.ssh

Tags: ssh, debian, vagrant

I am making a Vagrant base box out of debian wheezy amd64 with a minimal installation of ssh-server, virtualbox guest additions and a bit more.  I have added the insecure key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys and enabled key auth from sshd_config. ssh from the virtual machine to localhost works, so keys are ok. With vagrant package --base [vm name] --output  [file] it creates a box. When using vagrant up to boot the box (after add and init) SSH keys don't work because there is no .ssh in /home/vagrant/. What causes this and/or how to fix this?

Edit: "normal" virtual machine home:

```
vagrant@debudebu:~$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 14:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Feb  4 15:39 ..
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 13:50 .aptitude
-rw------- 1 vagrant vagrant 2570 Feb 10 15:04 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  220 Feb  4 15:39 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 3392 Feb  4 15:39 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 14:41 keys
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb  4 22:56 .links2
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  675 Feb  4 15:39 .profile
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 14:55 .ssh
```

vagrant box home:

```
vagrant@debudebu:~$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 14:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Feb  4 15:39 ..
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 10 13:50 .aptitude
-rw------- 1 vagrant vagrant 2570 Feb 10 14:23 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  220 Feb  4 15:39 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 3392 Feb  4 15:39 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb  4 22:56 .links2
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  675 Feb  4 15:39 .profile
```

Keys and .ssh are missing.

Comment: "insecure key": um, what's that?

Comment: Vagrant insecure key pair is the default key Vagrant uses to authenticate ssh sessions to the vagrant virtual machine.  https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys.

Comment: @MarcusMüller its a "default" ssh key  which is used for baseboxes so that they could run on any vagrant installation without any customization (have a look at the vagrant repository on github)

Comment: @SebastianStigler just did that :)

Comment: @KalleAlanen How did you add the key? Did you do it by hand or did you us some kind of script / provisioning tool?

Comment: @KalleAlanen just to check if I understand your steps correct:  1. You installed Wheezy in a VM. 2. You installed ssh-server, guest-addons ... 3. You add the insecure key to `/home/vagrant/.ssh/autherized_keys` 4. you shutdown the VM. 5. Called `vagrant package ...` 6. Add the box and init it. 7. vagrant up / vagrant ssh complains about ssh.

Comment: @KalleAlanen Did you make a vm snapshot before you added the ssh  key? Perhaps `vagrant package...` uses the last snapshot and not the "current stat" of the vm to create a vagrant-box.

Comment: @SebastianStigler I added it by hand. Steps are correct. I did not make a snapshot. AFAIK I need to add the keys to the VM before packaging so I can ssh in on the first go.

Comment: On other machine I did the same steps, but there SSH keys work...

Comment: Problem solved itself. Most likely there was some old stuff from previous packaging (one that did not have the keys) in the directory. Switching directory and re-running add and init fixed the problem.